# Address of register variable when it is taken as auto variable

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose, if no registers are available in CPU, then `register` variable is taken as `auto` variable. Then can we apply `&` operator to it?

Also, is there any way to check whether a variable with `register` storage class is stored in CPU or not?

Comment: What's the purpose of the required information? How does it help?

Comment: No, register variable is not "taken as auto variable". 

The C standard determines what you can and cannot do in a valid C program. It says you cannot take an address of a register variable.

The C standard does not concern itself with your CPU architecture, or whether you have any CPU indeed. As far as the standard is concerned, your program may be evaluated by a squad of highly trained squirrels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't. The standard is quite clear on this what operators are allowed to be applied on a `register` storaged-classed variable regardless of whether an actual register is used or not:

**C11, 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers, p6**

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as
>   possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined. <sup>121</sup>
>
> 121) The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as
>   an auto declaration. However, **whether or not addressable storage is
>   actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with
>   storage-class specifier register cannot be computed, either explicitly**
>   (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly
>   (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1).
>   **Thus, the only operators that can be applied to an array declared with
>   storage-class specifier register are sizeof and _Alignof**.

*(emphasis mine)*

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not allowed to apply `&` to a variable with the `register` storage specifier, regardless of whether it's stored in a register or not.
(The code must be valid even if a particular compiler can't allocate a register for it on a particular platform.)

Section 6.5.3.2 [Address and indirection operators] says

> The operand of the unary & operator shall be either a function
>   designator, the result of a
>       [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>       not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

The way to check whether a variable actually is stored in a register is to inspect the generated code.